# How to perform Drag and Drop using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, drag-and-drop

Below I have given my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html")
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
print(browser.title)


source_element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='DHTMLgoodies_dragableElement5']")
target_element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='box106']")
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.drag_and_drop(source_element,target_element).perform()
```

My output:-

```
/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/draganddrop.py
Demo 2: Drag and drop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/draganddrop.py", line 21, in <module>
    actions.drag_and_drop(source_element,target_element).perform()
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 75, in perform
    self.w3c_actions.perform()
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/action_builder.py", line 77, in perform
    self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined
Stacktrace:
element.getInViewCentrePoint@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:1185:5
getElementCenter@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.js:1497:22
dispatchPointerMove/<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.js:1378:34
dispatchPointerMove@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.js:1374:10
toEvents/<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.js:1145:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.js:1055:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.js:1023:20
action.dispatch@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.js:1029:5
performActions@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:459:18
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:144:31

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I could not able to drag and drop it.
How to do the Perform action? I have tried many ways but I could not able to find a correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *`drag_and_drop()`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html")
  drag = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'box') and text()='Rome']")))
  drop = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'box') and text()='South Korea']")))
  ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(drag, drop).perform()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: dhtmlgoodies]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html')
time.sleep(5)
drg = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dropContent']//div[@class='dragableBox' and @id='box5']")
drp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='countries']//div[@class='dragableBoxRight' and @id='box105']")
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(drg, drp).perform()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/222CN.png)

Comment: I tried the above code. Its not working. When i run this code. Now it opens two more ads windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html')
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html")
drag = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'box') and text()='Rome']")))
drop = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'box') and text()='South Korea']")))
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(drag, drop).perform()


'''drg = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dropContent']//div[@class='dragableBox' and @id='box5']")
drp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='countries']//div[@class='dragableBoxRight' and @id='box105']")
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(drg, drp).perform()
time.sleep(5)'''
#driver.quit()
```

This is the modified code.
Now its working. Thank you so much for the help.
[image]
[image]